# html 5 attribute as array of object being treated as string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I am trying to create a code snippet that fetches google map objects like location, marker text from database and add it to html data-attributes so I can use them in javascript easily

I am unable to make js understand the json as json , its rather being treated as string

```js
 jQuery('.map_canvazz').each(function(i,elem) {
  latPos   = jQuery(this).attr("data-lat");
  longPos   = jQuery(this).attr("data-long");
  infoDisplay  = jQuery(this).attr("data-info");
  var objAddresses= jQuery(this).attr("data-params");
        
      if(typeof objAddresses != 'undefined'){
   console.log(typeof(objAddresses));
   console.log(objAddresses);
   //array of object is treated as string
            // unable to convert array of objects as json
            // todo :- loop through the object of array
  }
      
      })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='map_canvazz' id='maper1'   data-params='[{"lat":"-36.758435","long":"144.273174","mapTxt":"<div class=\"mapArea\"><div class=\"lineOneMap\">Beyond Medical Education Victorian Office<\/div><div class=\"lineTwoMap\">37 Rowan Street<br>Bendigo VIC 3550, Australia<br>+61 35441 9300<\/div><\/div>"},{"lat":"1111","long":"222","mapTxt":"test"}]'></div>     </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.data()` jq method. It will parse it to array:

```js
jQuery('.map_canvazz').each(function(i, elem) {
  var objAddresses = jQuery(this).data("params");
  for (var i = 0; i < objAddresses.length; i++) {
    var obj = objAddresses[i];
    console.log(obj.lat, obj.long, obj.mapTxt);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='map_canvazz' id='maper1' data-params='[{"lat":"-36.758435","long":"144.273174","mapTxt":"<div class=\"mapArea\"><div class=\"lineOneMap\">Beyond Medical Education Victorian Office<\/div><div class=\"lineTwoMap\">37 Rowan Street<br>Bendigo VIC 3550, Australia<br>+61 35441 9300<\/div><\/div>"},{"lat":"1111","long":"222","mapTxt":"test"}]'></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Attribute values can only be strings. If you want to convert a string of JSON into a JavaScript object then you should run it through `JSON.parse()`.

Comment: I tried using JSON.parse() and I get following error
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data